# Can I use LISA bonus with a Help To Buy equity loan if the property is worth more than £450k?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I'm looking to buy a flat in London. I'd had a Lifetime ISA for 2 years which I've maxed out both times (~£10k). I'm also looking to get a Help to Buy equity loan, probably for the maximum of 40%, unless there's a compelling reason not to.

The equity loan is not limited by any specific value but the property must be a new-build.

I am only eligible to receive the LISA bonus if ["the property costs £450,000 or less"](https://www.gov.uk/lifetime-isa) but I'm not sure whether that refers to the full property *value*.

Suppose I wanted to purchase property for £460,000. I have a deposit of around £50,000. The equity loan would be £184,000, leaving a mortgage of £226,000.

Am I able to claim the LISA bonus in such a case? I found the following on [moneysavingexpert](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/lifetime-isas/) but I don't think it's worded very well. It looks like I *couldn't* but it'd be good to know for sure.

> To get the bonus you'll just need to buy a property that costs
>   £450,000 or less with any residential mortgage (not buy to let). **That
>   includes Right to Buy, shared ownership, self-builds, and Help to Buy
>   loans.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the gov.uk page you linked to and quoted is perfectly clear - the property must cost £450,000 or less. It says nothing about how you are paying for that cost or in what proportions.

Look at it another way - if someone bought a £100k house with a £10k deposit, a £40k loan and a £50k mortgage, and someone else asked them how much it cost - the answer would be £100k.

So, no, you cannot claim the LISA bonus to buy a £460,000 house.